# CTE vs multiple inserts

Tags: sql-server, insert, common-table-expression

As we all know, CTEs were introduced in SQL Server 2005 and the crowd went wild.

I have a case where I'm inserting a whole lot of static data into a table. What I want to know is which of the following is faster and what other factors I should be aware of.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) VALUES ('Hello')
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) VALUES ('World')
```

or

```
WITH MyCTE(Field1) AS (SELECT 'Hello' UNION SELECT 'World')
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) SELECT Field1 FROM MyCTE
```

I have an uncomfortable feeling the answer will be dependent on things like what triggers exist on `MyTable`...

(Also, I know and don't care that `BULK INSERT`ing a CSV and any number of other methods are objectively faster and better ways of inserting static data. I specifically want to know the concerns I should be aware of with a CTE vs multiple inserts.)

Comment: Easy solution: TEST TEST TEST and measure! It's really hard to say from afar, without knowing your system, your disk layout, your table layout etc. Indicies, triggers, lots more will play a role. So really: only **you** can tell by testing and measuring the two approaches.....

Comment: marc_s, yes testing and profiling are always the best way to get the an answer to your exact set of circumstances, but I was looking for some more general trends and considerations to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version of SQL Server you're using (2005 or 2008) - but no matter which version you use, I don't see any big benefit in using a CTE in this case for multiple inserts, quite honestly. CTE's are indeed great for a great many situation - but this is not one of them.

So basically, I would suggest you just use several `INSERT` statements.

In SQL Server 2008, you could simplify those by just specifying multiple values tuples:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) 
VALUES ('Hello'), ('World'), ('and outer space')
```

As always, your table structure, presence (or absence) of indices and triggers does indeed have a significant impact on your INSERT speed. If you need to load a lot of data, it's sometimes easier to turn these constraints and triggers OFF for the duration of the INSERT and then back on - but again: there's really no way to give you a clear indication whether that's the case in your specific situation or not - just too many variables we don't know about that play a siginificant role. Measure it, compare it, make a decision for yourself!

Comment: +1: My chat with Quassnoi a while back suggested that there is no speed improvement using a CTE vs an inline view.

Comment: @OMGPonies: I would support that - but sometimes, I find CTE's to be more readable and more easily understood than complicated nested inline views. No performance benefit per se, but easier to read

Comment: @OMGPonies, I'd deliberately excluded things like temporary tables, but I hadn't thought of inline views. Good point. Can you give a link to the chat you're referring to?

@marc_s, I wasn't aware of that new syntax for SQL 2008. Thanks!